# Unparseable Date:"Sat Oct 12 09:05:00 IST 2013" exception

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I need to parse a string to date. But getting an unparseable exception.
Following is my code:

```
String str="Sat Oct 12 09:05:00 IST 2013";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM DD hh:mm:ss yyyy");
try {
   format.parse(str);
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format has several issues:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

- `D` denotes day in year, not day in month
- You're missing the time zone
- The format for month is incorrect
- Since you're time is in 24-hour format, you need `H` instead of `h`

Refer to [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for information on *Date and Time Patterns*.

Comment: I suspect `hh` should be `HH` too since the format has no am/pm.

Answer (score 1):

Your format for parsing that string is wrong. You need to use this format.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"); // Default Locale
```

- MMM - is the proper month format in your case
- z - you missed the pattern for timezone
- d - represents the day in the month not D which represents day in the year.
- And as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396536/unparseable-datesat-oct-12-090500-ist-2013-exception#comment34050621_22396593), you might want to use `H` instead of `h` as the hour seems to be in the 24-hour format.

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about the *Date and Time Patterns*.