# Java parsing String date to MilliSecond

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How do I convert date string `'Fri Mar 14 09:44:31 IST 2014'` to `millisec`?

I tried with this Java code:

```
String dateStr = "Fri Mar 14 09:44:31 IST 2014";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd HH:MM:ss");
try {
    System.out.println(sdf.parse(dateStr).getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unparseable Date:"Sat Oct 12 09:05:00 IST 2013" exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396536/unparseable-datesat-oct-12-090500-ist-2013-exception)

Answer (score 2):

your `SimpleDateFormat` is not correct.

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Comment: HH:MM:ss will convert 09:44:31 to hour=9, months=44,seconds=31. you have to use HH:mm:ss

Comment: thanks @JaemokLee for reminding me that. I have edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

try following code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```